# IntelliJ ApectJ post-compile time weaving

Tags: java, intellij-idea, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have the following aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class DefaultStringAspect {

    @Around(value = "execution(* org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.defaultString(..))")
    public Object defaultString(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        return "DEF";
    }  
}
```

This aspect is applied to a classpath library. It works fine with maven configuration below:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                ..
                <configuration>
                   ..
                    <weaveDependencies>
                        <weaveDependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                        </weaveDependency>
                    </weaveDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

When I try to build the project from IntelliJ IDEA, the aspect is not applied. The aspect itself is compiled, but woven dependencies are not. I've tried to adjust `ajc` command line options taken from maven's debug output and add them to IntelliJ:

> -showWeaveInfo
>   -verbose
>   -classpath ...
>   -inpath ...
>   -d ...

but this didn't work for me.
Any other ideas how to force IntelliJ to use the same `ajc` configuration as maven?

Comment: You can [delegate build/run actions to Maven](https://i.imgur.com/61cJ9l7.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks, it works for me.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, please transform your comment into an answer and embed the screenshot rather than just linking to it. The OP can then accept and thus close the question which is still listed as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven as a workaround (File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner):

[image: delegate]